# Standard deviation of recall, precision, accuracy and F-score?

Tags: standard-deviation, precision-recall

I'm not sure how to correctly calculate the **standard deviation** of recall, precision, accuracy and F-score.

For example:

```
TP  FP  FN  TN  total   recall   precision    F-Score    accuracy                           
40  10  15  50  115     0.727      0.800       0.762      0.783
```

TP = True Positive, FN = False Negative, etc.

*(Do I use the formula for standard deviation of a binomial distribution:
$\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$? OR $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$
with $n$ = total and $p$ = recall, precision, F-Score, or accuracy.)*

How can i calculate the standard deviation?

I'm not even sure if it makes sense but i was asked to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to even think of calculating the SD from a single observation you have to know the distribution of the measure, and it is not the case for the majority of predictive models.

Thus, you are left with non-parametric ways of estimating SD; for instance, you can cross-validate the model and then use the vector of precision/recall/F/acc values over folds.

Comment: yes i think you're right about the cross validation.

Comment: Hard to see this as a "single observation" when there are 115 cases observed.